# Setting environment variables for create-react-app hosted in azure not working

Tags: reactjs, azure, create-react-app

I've deployed a create-react-app to an azure app service as a windows node app.  The application runs fine, but instead of the variables I set in Application Settings, it's still using the ones from my .env.local file.  They all start with REACT_APP_ - so why isn't my application settings variables overriding that?  Per all the documentation I have seen, whatever I have in .env, the application settings in azure should override those with the ones I have in there when the app starts.  Am I missing a step somewhere?

For example, in my .env.local file, I have variable REACT_APP_API_APP_URL with a value of http://localhost/api.  But in my app settings in the app service, I have a setting named REACT_APP_API_APP_URL too, with a different value, but the localhost one is still showing in process.env.REACT_APP_API_APP_URL in the application when it runs in azure.